# Flex TextArea scroll down

Tags: apache-flex, textarea, scrollbar, vertical-scrolling

I have a `TextArea` that shows the conversation from selected chat room. For `valueCommit` event I use: `verticalScrollPosition = maxVerticalScrollPosition;` And it works fine scrolling text to the bottom. However in one case it doesn't work as expected. There's verylittle text, so TextArea has no scrollbar and then I put a lot of text and a scrollbar is necessary. The text is scrolled almost to the bottom (still a few lines need to be scrolled down). I am pretty sure it gets `maxVerticalScrollPosition` as if there was no scrollbar. So the question is how can I wait with updating verticalScrollPosition with respect to `TextArea's` new size (that is now with a scrollbar). I tried calling `validateSize` and other methods that start with 'validate' but unfortunately with no luck. I also tried the old trick of putting caret at the end of text. So the `TextArea's` scrollbar makes a difference when getting `maxVerticalScrollPosition` and I need to update `verticalScrollPosition` once all measurements are done.

I forgot to mention. I use `htmlText`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the issue is fixed after you add additional text again, you could probably get by using a `Timer`, or a call to `setTimeout` and have the `verticalScrollPosition = maxVerticalScrollPosition` called a fraction of a second later and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about some more elegant solution, but 50ms delay is not that bad after all.

Comment: I'm not sure, it works in every case. LayoutManager can decide not to update this `TextArea` in current frame, or current frame scripts/renders can take longer, or timer can fire twice a frame before `TextArea` updates. All this can break mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments of the answer you accepted you mentioned a more elegant solution.  Yeah, a timer probably isn't the best option -- you have eventListener cleanup if you remove the component from the stage; if you use the component more than once, you have another timer instance; etc., etc.

If you don't have a lot of post-commit-property actions, the quickest solution would be a call later on the setter of text or htmlText

```
override public function set text(value:String):void
{
    super.text = value;

    callLater( scrollToEndAfterTextCommitted );
}

protected function scrollToEndAfterTextCommitted():void
{
    this.verticalScrollPosition = this.maxVerticalScrollPosition;
}
```

I hope that helps.
Best of luck!